# checking if there're equal bits in binary string

Tags: randomized-algorithms, randomness

We have two binary strings, $X$ and $Y$, in two different computers. Both of them in length $n$. The computers can communicate by sending bits to each other.

We have to build randomized algorithm to check whether there's an index $i$ such that $X_i=Y_i$. We can send only $O(\log n)$ bits between the computers.

If there's no such index the algorithm will always return "false". If there's such index, the algorithm will return "true" in probability 0.5 (at least).

Any suggestions?

Comment: **Any suggestions?** Yes: do not cross-post. It is not well regarded. You should remove one of your two posts.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is the classical problem of EQUALITY in disguise, a problem whose randomized communication complexity is known to be $O(\log n)$. In other words, you can reduce your problem to EQUALITY.